# What does "unexpected response code for operation : 1" mean?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

Am getting "unexpected response code for operation : 1" from an app trying to insert records in an Azure table storage.

Am basically placing the data in a TableOperation and already batching the inserts by 100 row chunks.

Can't really find much on the web about the specific "1" code in this Azure error message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the batch operation fails, table service returns HTTP status code 400 and along with that it sends the index of the entity which caused this batch to fail.

> "unexpected response code for operation : 1"

This means there's an error while inserting entity at position 1 in your batch.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for spending the time to view my question and posting a helpful answer.

When we say Position 1, would that mean the first entity to be inserted?

When I break and check the table storage, it actually inserts 5 rows on the first batch; but is supposed to be 100. Then it will insert the same 5 rows until it triggers this error.

Comment: `When we say Position 1, would that mean the first entity to be inserted` - That would be 2nd entity because the index starts at 0. Can you post the request data that is sent to Windows Azure Table Storage? You can get this data by capturing the requests through a tool like Fiddler.

Comment: Gaurav, I deeply thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It really was a problem with malformed data :(

Comment: I put together a [guide to using Fiddler to debug this error](http://amadeusw.com/debugging/debugging-azure-with-fiddler/). Use it to find meaningful error information. In my case, the data I've sent was too large.